# Can I request to remove a Facebook page that were hacked/hijacked from me?

Tags: facebook, hacked, copyright

I tried everything from Facebook support to recover my page but they said since it was a friendly hack, they couldn’t give me back my admin rights and there’s no hope for me to recover the page anymore that was stolen. I have a website with the same name,  that was connected to Facebook instant article before but of course the hacker removed it already. I reported for intellectual infringement to claim my brand name and sending them my registered domain name as a proof that I own the page’s name, logo and contents since I have a website registered a year ago but up to this point Facebook hasn’t replied yet. They only removed the copyrighted contents that I reported but the page is still up and running, and worse is that the hackers are reposting my old posts from the Facebook page pretending to be me and replying to my followers as if they were me. I’m losing all hope to Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

You can report here:
[I Have an Issue Accessing My Page](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/1280439701975125)

See this below official link for hacked Page and account:
[I think my Page was hacked or taken over by someone else.](https://www.facebook.com/help/131719720300233)

> Note that Facebook can only take action on your report if Facebook can confirm that the person was hacked.
>
> Keep in mind that you may have also lost access to your Page if your Page was reported and removed for [infringing someone's intellectual property rights](https://www.facebook.com/help/399224883474207?helpref=faq_content).